# Qt открыть URL в popup браузере

Tags: android, qt, ios, mobile-development, jni

Как в Qt Android/iOS открыть внешнюю ссылку в браузере по умолчанию во всплывающем окне?

Qt.openUrlExternally() - не подходит, так как эта команда открывает новую вкладку в браузере и переходит из окна приложения Qt в окно браузера. WebView - не подходит, нуужно чтобы это был именно браузер по умолчанию выбранный в ОС.

В других приложениях такая возможность есть, когда ссылка открывается не в окне браузера, а во всплывающем окне над Qt приложением. Если это Android, то в открывшемся всплывающем окне слева вверху - кнопка закрытия окна, справа вверху - кнопка "поделиться" и кнопка опций, по нажатию на нее вот такое меню:

[image: меню всплывающего окна-браузера на Android]

В iOS окно всплывающего браузера выглядит так:

[image: Всплывающее окна-браузер в iOS]